# Passing dates to the stored procedure and get details in return to display in html table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am entering start date and end date. When i click on view Graph button the details present between this date range should come in the table.
Here is the html view page:
[image]

When i click on view graph button I am getting an error "The server responded with status 404http://localhost:5555/api/ProjectDetails/GetTableSubmittedDetails/01/20/2017/06/30/2017?Year=01%2F20%2F2017&Rtype=06%2F30%2F2017 "

Here is my html code:

```
   <div class="row div_Align">
                <div class="col-lg-8">

                    <label class="control-label">
                        Start Date &nbsp;<span class="Imp"></span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" id="departing">

                    <label class="control-label">
                        End Date &nbsp;<span class="Imp"></span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" id="returning">
              <input type="button"
                           value="View Graphs"
                           id="btnViewGraph" onclick="ViewGraph();" class="btn btn-default" /> &nbsp;
                </div>

            </div>

  <div class="row div_Align" style="padding-bottom:0px;">
                <table id="TicketTable" class="table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style="margin-bottom:8px;border:1px solid lightgrey;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:10%; padding-left:15px; " ng-click="vm.sotData('Ticket_No')">
                                Ticket No
                                <span ng-class="vm.getSortClass('Ticket_No')"></span>
                            </th>
                            <th style="width:12%" ng-click="vm.sotData('Executioncyclename')">
                                Execution Cycle
                                <span ng-class="vm.getSortClass('Executioncyclename')"></span>
                            </th>
       </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Angular js code:

```
function ViewGraph() {
    startdate = $("#departing").val();
    enddate = $("#returning").val();
    BindTable(startdate, enddate);

}

 function BindTable(startdate, enddate) {

            var url = webApiUrl + 'api/ProjectDetails/GetTableSubmittedDetails/' + startdate + '/' + enddate;
            $('#TicketTable > tbody > tr ').remove();

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "Get",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { Year: startdate, Rtype: enddate },
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (data) {

                    var tr;
                    var totalTestPreparation = 0;
                    var totalTestExecution = 0;
                    var totalTestDebugActivities = 0;
                    var totalTestReporting = 0;
                    var totalOFTotal = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var ticketNo = data[i].Ticket_No;
                        var executioncyCycleName = data[i].Executioncyclename;

                        tr = $('<tr/>');
                       tr.append("<td>" + ticketNo + "</td>");
                       tr.append("<td>" + executioncyCycleName + "</td>");

                    }
                    tr = $('<tr style="font-weight: bold; background-color: white" />');
                    tr.append("<td></td>");
                    tr.append("<td></td>");
 $('#TicketTable').append(tr);
        }
            });

        }
```

I have tested the stored procedure which takes the input dates from here and gives the result. Stored procedure works fine. I feel there is something I am missing with web api call or angular js side. Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `startdate`  and `endate` in your url because `/` characters are not encoded

```
var url = webApiUrl + 'api/ProjectDetails/GetTableSubmittedDetails/'
```

And they are note required in your url because you pass them as data in your ajax query.

Another thing : you don't use angular for your query but jquery. To use angular you need to use :
[$http.get(...)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)